# "this" not working and being called a function

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a snake game, and I am using canvas to write down the code. When i want to make a this, and i want to draw a square, suddenly my this is being called a function. I am very confused and i need help. Any advice? Here is the code:

```
const cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

const width = cvs.width;
const height = cvs.height

const blockSize = 10
const widthInBlocks = width / blockSize;
const heightInBlocks = height / blockSize;

const score = 0;

// This code is for the border
ctx.fillStyle = "Gray"
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, blockSize, height);
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, blockSize);
ctx.fillRect(0, height - blockSize, width, blockSize);
ctx.fillRect(width - blockSize, 0, blockSize, height);

// Code for keeping track of score
ctx.font = "20px Courier";
ctx.fillStyle = "Black"
ctx.textAlign = "left"
ctx.textBaseline = "top"
ctx.fillText("Score: " + score, blockSize, blockSize)

var Block = function(col, row) {
  this.col = col;
  this.row = row;
}

var sampleBlock = new Block(5, 5);


Block.prototype.equal = function(otherBlock) {
  return this.col === otherBlock.col && this.row === otherBlock.row;
}

const Snake = function() {
  this.segments = [
    new Block(7, 5),
    new Block(6, 5),
    new Block(5, 5)
  ];

this.direction = "right";
this.nextDirection = "right"
};

Snake.prototype.draw = function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.segments.length; i++) {
     this.segments.drawSquare("Blue");
  }
};
var snake = new Snake();
snake.draw();
```

line 53 is the error.
the error is "this.segments[i].length is not a function"
I am confused, because its not even supposed to be a function.

Comment: A typo here? `this.segments.drawSquare("Blue");`

Comment: I think I can see a few issues in your code. First, you're trying to call a function called `drawSquare()` on your segments, and as far as I can tell `segments` is an array and you haven't assigned it any additional functions. In fact you haven't assigned the `drawSquare` function to anything. So when I run the code the bug I get is about that missing fn (maybe you left it out of your question)? As for the error, `segments[i]` is a `Block`, isn't it and I don't think it has a `length` function on it from what I can tell

Comment: Hi! so i am a new coder, and i am actually typing all this code from a book. for some reason i believe that the book never included this. can you show me a example?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you've updated your code since seeing the error on line 53?
(The script you posted doesn't include the code `this.segments[i].length`.)

The error you should see logged for the script you posted occurs in the line:

```
this.segments.drawSquare("Blue");
```

and looks like:

```
//Uncaught TypeError: this.segments.drawSquare is not a function (in Snake.draw)
```

Here, JavaScript is complaining that **there is no method called `drawSquare` on the `segments` object.** This is because you haven't defined any function called `drawSquare` (and also because `segments` is an array of blocks, and we don't usually add methods to arrays).

You probably want to add `drawSquare` as `Block.prototype.drawSquare`, and then call it for each `block` in the `snake.segments` array, something like:

```
for(let block of this.segments){
  block.drawSquare("blue");
}
```

---

So the complete script could look something like:

```js
    const
      cvs = document.getElementById("canvas"),
      ctx = cvs.getContext("2d"),
      width = cvs.width,
      height = cvs.height,

      blockSize = 10,
      widthInBlocks = width / blockSize,
      heightInBlocks = height / blockSize,
      score = 0;

    // Code for the border -- or would we use `.strokeRect`?
    ctx.fillStyle = "Gray"
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, blockSize, height);
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, blockSize);
    ctx.fillRect(0, height - blockSize, width, blockSize);
    ctx.fillRect(width - blockSize, 0, blockSize, height);

    // Code for tracking score
    ctx.font = "20px Courier";
    ctx.fillStyle = "Black"
    ctx.textAlign = "left"
    ctx.textBaseline = "top"
    ctx.fillText("Score: " + score, blockSize, blockSize)

    var Block = function(col, row) {
      this.col = col;
      this.row = row;
    }
    Block.prototype.equal = function(otherBlock) {
      return this.col === otherBlock.col && this.row === otherBlock.row;
    }
    Block.prototype.drawSquare = function(color){
      // TODO: Use `ctx` object to actually draw each square
      console.log("I am drawing a " + color + " Square at " + this.row + ", " + this.col);
      // (Note: here, `this` is a block made from the Block constructor
    }

    const Snake = function() {
      this.segments = [
        // The `new` keyword invokes a function as a constructor
        new Block(7, 5),
        new Block(6, 5),
        new Block(5, 5)
      ];
      this.direction = "right";
      this.nextDirection = "right"
    };
    Snake.prototype.draw = function() {
      const snake = this; // Clarifying what `this` points to
      const blocks = snake.segments; // Each segment is a block
      for (let block of blocks) {
         block.drawSquare("Blue"); // Calls block's method
      }
    };

    var snake = new Snake();
    snake.draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

---

**I leave it to you to implement the `drawSquare` method.** To do this, you'll [learn how to use the context object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D), a property of the canvas object, to add colored rectangles to the canvas.

That link goes to **MDN**, which is an excellent reference for (almost) all things web-related -- and if their documentation isn't clear enough, google other resources (or just play around with the built-in methods and add some console.log statements to see what happens.)  One other resource that may be worth mentioning at the start of your JavaScript career is the book [Eloquent JavaScript](https://eloquentjavascript.net/), which is available online.

(And I suspect you might see the type of `this` as "function" at some point in your code where the context for the `this` binding might be the `Snake` constructor function itself.)